# Android trying to center 2 Images, but they get right justfied

Tags: android, xml

I have a layout with a image of the card on the left hand side. The right hand side has 2 buttons on top. Then 2 images below them, and one image below the 2 images.

I would like the 2 images and 1 image to get centered.
The row with 1 image gets centred all right.

**PARTIAL CODE**

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/viewfacebook"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/viewmail"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/mail" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I create a horizontal container for the 2 images and set it's gravity to center.  This is not working.  I also tried to set the gravty to center on the 2 images.  But.... they always stay to the left hand side.

**THE WHOLE XML CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cardpic"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/bio" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/buthome"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/ok" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/butaffirmation"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/affirmation" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/viewfacebook"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/viewmail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/mail" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/vietwitter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/twitter" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/housetext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" *A long and happy marriage or commitment is in your future.\n*Emotional security (loyalty and trust) exists in your relationship.\n*You will have a stable home and family life.\nThe marriage card is about a person who is either going get married or who really cherishes the whole institution of marriage."
                android:textColor="#ff000000"
                android:textSize="18px"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cardtext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" *A long and happy marriage or commitment is in your future.\n*Emotional security (loyalty and trust) exists in your relationship.\n*You will have a stable home and family life.\nThe marriage card is about a person who is either going get married or who really cherishes the whole institution of marriage."
        android:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard to follow your XML, but this should get you on the right track, give this a try.

If you are using linear layouts...
Nest the images you want to center side by side in a horizontal linear layout
Assign a layout weight to each image
You might have to play around with the layout_widths and heights using match_parent (or fill depending on your target API), and also with the layout_gravity and gravity params.

```
<LinearLayout android:gravity="center" ... orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/viewmail"
    android:src="@drawable/mail" />

    <ImageView 
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/vietwitter"
    android:src="@drawable/twitter" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited the code within the question. I had a rough time trying to see what you were trying to do. A picture for the question might have been very straight forward (imo). Now to answer your question, understand that LinearLayouts have by default left-justification. If you have multiple LinearLayouts nested, take extra caution when deciding their widths and heights, as they take precedence over gravity.